# Using JWT between two Flask applications

Tags: python, flask, xmlhttprequest, jwt

I have two separate Flask applications, one is an API with the domain "admin.company.com" and the second one is a dashboard under the domain "dashboard.company.com".

My main goal is to secure the api and enable authentication.

I set up authentication on the api and when I'm testing it via the swagger-ui it works good with no issues. I manage to authenticate myself and submit requests. On top of that, in the `token_required()` below I coded a section that expects to receive JWT and decode it:

```
def token_required(f):
@wraps(f)
def decorator(*args, **kwargs):

    token = None

    if 'jwt-token' in request.headers:
        token = request.headers['jwt-token']

    if not token:
        return jsonify({'message': 'a valid token is missing'})

    try:
        current_user = False

        # for authentication via the swagger-ui
        if token == 'my_awesome_password':
            current_user = 'admin'
        else:
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.secret_key)
            current_user = 'admin' if data['public_id'] == 'admin' else False

        if not current_user:
            return jsonify({'message': 'token is invalid'})

    except:
        return jsonify({'message': 'token is invalid'})

    return f(*args, **kwargs)

return decorator
```

**The problem is with the dashboard application**:

On the dashboard app, I configured the `/login` route to generate JWT (which needs to be sent to the api app in every HTTP request I made), then do a `set_cookie()` with `httpOnly=True` flag (for security purposes), but then how can the JavaScript access it when it has to make XHR requests? Having the httpOnly flag on makes it unreachable.

If using `httpOnly=True` is not the ideal way in this case, how can I tackle it and make sure the JWT will always be sent to the api app in the request headers?

I'm using PyJWT package.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JWTs for XHR requests, then you don't necessarily need to use cookies – the browser/consumer could store the token and attach it to every request. If you do want to use cookies (this is also a viable option) then you don't need to worry about attaching the JWT as the browser will do that automatically for the domains you specified in the `set_cookie` command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In `set_cookie()` I specified `domain=".company.com"` and the jwt doesn't appear in the request headers when checking it in Chrome's network inspect.

Comment: From the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie), it seems there's nothing wrong. Are both domains using HTTP or HTTPS? Maybe you need to share the code where you set the cookie in context.

Comment: How does the header in the response look like, where you set the cookie?

Comment: Both domains using HTTP at the moment. This is the set_cookie code: `resp = make_response(redirect(url_for('index')))
            resp.set_cookie('jwt-token', value=token, domain=".company.com", httponly=True)`